# Lavavel 8 disable translation, response with field name and rule

Tags: laravel, validation, translation

I have simply issue but I stucked. I need to disable translations for validators only. For example, let field **name** has rule **max:80**. When validation fails, I want to response with json:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "name": {
            "max": 80
        },
    },
    "status": "error"
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it? I made my own **Translator** (which extends *\Illuminate\Translation\Translator*) and I figured out, that I could check if translations comes from **validation.php** file, and replace the value with translation's key. But this solution apears to be very ugly.

EDIT:
I decide to leave translations. Problem is with validation, not with translations. So I made **CustomValidator** class

```
namespace App\Overrides;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * Determine if the data passes the validation rules.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes(): bool
    {
        return parent::passes();
    }
}
```

and factory for it:

```
namespace App\Overrides;

use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;

class ValidatorFactory extends Factory
{
    protected function resolve(array $data, array $rules, array $messages, array $customAttributes )
    {
        if (is_null($this->resolver)) {
            return new CustomValidator($this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
        }

        return call_user_func($this->resolver, $this->translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
    }
}
```

then I swapped the factory

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Overrides\ValidatorFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->extend('validator', function () {
            return $this->app->get(ValidatorFactory::class);
        });
    }
```

But there is a new problem. Validation's rules used database (like "unique") throwns ecxeption: **Presence verifier has not been set**. Other rules doesn't.

Comment: did you try setLocale('en') just before the validation method call?

Comment: I use custom RequestClass for each request to define the field's rules. Lang 'en' is my default language.

Comment: your translation needs for some other language, right? so your can change it to default in your constructor of the request

Comment: No, we can assume, that I need validator without translation in any language. I just want to get failed rule and related form's field name.

Comment: by default the validation failed errors are sent as an array or errors with keys as column/field names

Comment: @Psycho, therefore I want to change this default behavior. I made `CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator` and `ValidatorFactory` (I added code to my post) but I got a new issue extra :/

Comment: @Psycho, keys are good, but errors aren't like I want. For example, the message **The name may not be greater than 80 characters.** I want to replace with the json `{"name": {"max": 80}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$validator->failed();` is the answer.

It contains all failed rules:

```
array:2 [
  "name" => array:1 [
    "Max" => array:1 [
      0 => "80"
    ]
  ]
  "password" => array:1 [
    "Regex" => array:1 [
      0 => "/[a-z]/"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: okay, that's what you were looking for. I was more concerned about translation